# Using class as a key for a hash?

Tags: ruby

I've just realized that I am using class type as a key for a hash variable:
(not this exactly)

```
def add_to_cache(obj)
  @cache[obj.class] = [] unless @cache.has_key? obj.class
  @cache[obj.class] << obj
end
```

So I am curious if anyone can explain it. Is there some downside? How is it stored in memory? Should I convert it (obj.class) into Symbol or String rather?

Comment: Nah. Class itself is an object anyway. Anything in ruby is object and you can freely use them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby you can have any object being a key of a hash. The method `hash` of the object is called for the actual hashing. I assume this method is optimized enough and good enough for `Class`. Converting the class to string or symbol here is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that your objective might be to keep track of all instances of a certain class. If that is the case, then you do not need to, and should not, cache them manually. To get all instances of class `klass`, do this:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(klass).to_a
```

Comment: It was very simplified example only for explaining myself, thanks though, good to know something like this. i love ruby. Anyway, do you know how's performance of using this?